# count number of levels of iframe nesting in cross-site situation

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

If my page is buried several iframes deep, is it possible to count how many levels down I am (cross-domain)?

(I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I'm almost certain there's no way to do that.

You might try something like

```
var current = window;
while (current.parent != current) {
    current = current.parent;
}
```

, but I suspect you will fail with multiple domains, due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Might be worth a shot, though. Maybe access is blocked to document contents only, and not to window object.

Comment: I tried something similar testing for `current == top` which results in an infinite loop, since 'top` and `window.parent` are 'undefined`.

Comment: @sprugman window.top and window.parent are not `undefined` - they are simply the same object as parent and top will point to the `window` object if no 'real' parent exist.

Comment: From now on you can be certain - there is absolutely no way to get this information, as you say, due to the SOP.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the # of levels but in this way seems that you can identify if your content has been iframed more than once:

```
if (parent !== window) {
    //I'm iframed once for sure 
}
if (parent !== top) {
    //I'm iframed more than once
}
```

Tested with Chrome 59, Safari 10, Firefox 54, Edge 15, IE11